# No sound in Cave Story+

Tags: cave-story

I have the Steam version of Cave Story+ and this is the first time I've encountered this problem. When I open the game, there is no music or sound effects. I checked the settings and music and sound effects are both on max, I checked the volume mixer in Windows and it is showing no sound coming from Cave Story+. Its not muted and volume is up. I already tried reinstalling the game but there is still no sound. I'm playing on Windows 10.

EDIT: Today I tried using a pair of analog headphones I had with my computer to see if that would work. Cave Story+ DOES have sound when I use those, but not with my USB Razer Kraken 7.1. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. In the Razer Synapse software used with the Razer Kraken 7.1 headphones, Cave Story+ was muted for some reason.